# Django dynamic ListView filtering problem

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on my first solo project with Django and I have hit a problem that no amount of searching and reading similar post on SO have solved.

I am trying to filter a gallery of images by their category, so that when the user clicks on a picture it will result in a page showing all the images with the same category. This will use HTMX hopefully in the final product, but I'm trying and failing to implement it using regular Django views initially.

As I said, this is my first solo project, so I'm very much a beginner, I know this isn't a debug service but just wanted some pointers on where I could be going wrong. Another set of eyes as you will.

I followed the docs on dynamic filtering CBV. I have overwritten `get_queryset` passing the Category slug into the `kwargs` and I have overwritten the `get_context_data`so I can pass `slug` into the template.

I am getting a `Reverse for 'select' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['select/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']` error, so I belive the problem is in my template/URLconf.

Models. Media with a FK to it's Category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')`

class Media(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    url = models.URLField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    visable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Views, IndexView is entire gallery and SelectView is image by category

```
class IndexView(ListView):

    template_name = "main/index.html"
    model = Media

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['main_images'] = Media.objects.filter(visable=True)
        return context


class SelectView(ListView):

    template_name = "main/select.html"
    model = Media

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, title=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Media.objects.filter(categories__title=self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = self.category
        return context
```

URLconf with select being the relevant pattern.

```
app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("about", views.AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
    path("contact", views.ContactView.as_view(), name="contact"),
    path("select/<slug:slug>", views.SelectView.as_view(), name="select"),
]
```

Gallery template I have a for loop to display the IndexView. I think the problem is with the Href (which I want to take my to SelectView). I am passing slug in the {% url %} but think it should be image.categories__slug? I have tried this but it still doesn't work. I am stumped.

```
{% for image in main_images %}
        <div class="cbp-item web-design print"> 
<a href="{% url "main:select" slug %}" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePageInline">

<div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{ image.image.url }}"alt=""> </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be sending any value in the slug in "{% url "main:select" slug %}", so Django thinks it's just an empty sting.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to access the `slug` field on the `image.categories` field for each iteration.

```
{% for image in main_images %}
     ... 
     <a href="{% url 'main:select' image.cateogries.slug %}" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePageInline">
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

In addition to that, I'd recommend that you do a lookup for the receiving `slug` instead of the `title` on the `Category` model. For example, if you should save `I love this day` as the `title`, the `slug` field would have `I-love-this-day`.

What you have:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, title=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return Media.objects.filter(categories__title=self.category)
```

`title=self.kwargs['slug']` won't find a `title` if your passing `I-love-this-day` as the `slug`. I'd suggest using `slug=self.kwargs['slug']`. See the below updates:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # Also, the self keyword is not needed here either -> self.category
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])  # updated
    return Media.objects.filter(categories__title=category.title)  # updated
```

Additionally, I see where you're passing `slug` as a value via the `context` variable within the `SelectView`... I suggest you pass the category object explicitly via the `context` variable to the template where you can access the fields from your template if necessary.

Within the `get_context_data()`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # context['slug'] = self.category
    context['category'] = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks for this in depth reply. It really helps and I will go through it to try and fully understand it. I tired your changes but still get a `NoReverseMatch at /` error though. But, If i goto for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/select/news` that works and I get back 'news' category images.

Comment: Hold on. I'm pretty sure this is working now. I deleted any images without a Category and the view now seems to be working! Thanks so much. I'll study this and try and fully understand what is happening. I have gained a lot from this problem, but thanks again this was a real hold-up for my learning and effecting my confidence.

Comment: No problem bro. It's when you face the challenges you get an opportunity to learn more by research and asking questions. :-)